# How do I use rar to encrypt files including the file list in the command line?

Tags: linux, encryption, rar

I know I can do the following below to encrypt the files, but for the life of me I can't figure or find out how to encrypted the file list too.

```
rar a -p rarfile.rar myfiles
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
  hp[password]  Encrypt both file data and headers
```

Answer (score 7):

Here are command lines that can be used:

```
rar a -hp "rarfile"
```

this will ask for password twice before to create rarfile.rar

```
rar a -hpYourPassword "rarfile"
```

this will use YourPassword as password and create rarfile.rar